# Additional properties for UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uilabel

How can I add a property of `int` type to a `UILabel` that I created inside a View Controller?

I want to be able to use something like:

```
if (MyLabel.MyOwnProperty == 0) {

}
```

How can I create this `.MyNewProperty` of `int` type?

I tried:

```
 @property(nonatomic, assign) int *MyOwnProperty;
```

But it doesn't work with Labels, being written in the View Controller's `.h` file, only with [self], which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You will need to create a subclass of UILabel.

Comment: So, there is no way to avoid creating a new class?

Comment: Yes, you will need to subclass. Alternatively, all UIViews have a `tag` int property, that you might be able to use?

Comment: a subset of the `UILabel` could help.

Comment: The .tag is already in use =) I need the two more of them for my idea to work.
Well, I.ve created a new class od UILabel and added @property lines in its .h. my newly created UIlabels in the UIViewController are now of this new class. But still they don't have this property.

Comment: Have you synthesized them?

Comment: What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: I tried to do it either UILabel's Class .m nor in the Viewcontroller's .m.
For the latter one I used the following:
"@implementation HitClass
@synthesize MyOwnAction;
@end"

Comment: @Wain I've got several UILabels created in one "for" cycle.
I control them, depending on their tags (let's say, from 1 to 7).
Now I want this label to be randomly divided into three groups, so I want to give every of them something like:
"MyLabel.MyOwnProperty=(arc4random() %3)+1;"
And then divide them, using the "if" statement.

Comment: You can use category + associated objects (read http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to mimic having new properties in an existing class. But this should be considered as a solution of last resort. The better way should be having those labels subclasses of `UILabel` that you can add your new properties.

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit
Already created a subclass for them. Now I'm trying to create this properties (in .h of the subclass), synthesize them (tried both .m of subclass and of the View controller),  and let them to be used in the View Controller's .m

Comment: synthesize properties is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UILabel`

```
@interface MyLabel : UILabel

@property(nonatomic, assign) int MyOwnProperty;

@end
```

then you access its new property whatever you want.